# How to sent JSON data whiten JSON Object from the POST request

Tags: json, jackson, postman, spring-restcontroller

How to sent JSON data to whiten JSON Object from the POST request in POST body the Spring Rest controller.
I need to save this data to Postgres DB which is the column type is JSON.

I need to send bellow JSON from the PostMan as POST request to the SPring Rest controller but I can not hold the data in my controller, Its coming null to the controller but when I am giving List  I am getting below error.

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
>   "path": "/configJsondata"

Input Json From Postman is :

```
{
 "GenericValidation":[{"MinimumFieldsCheck":true},{"MirrorCopyAccountCheck":true},{"DuplicateAccountCheck":false},{"CleanClaimCheck":false},{"Segregating":true}],
 "HL7Specification":[{"MinimumFieldsCheck":true},{"MirrorCopyAccountCheck":true},{"DuplicateAccountCheck":false},{"CleanClaimCheck":false},{"Segregating":true}]
}

@PostMapping(value = "facility/insertConfig")
public ResponseEntity<?> insertCoderConfiguration(@RequestBody CoderConfigvalue requestvalue) {
int status = 0;
try {

    status = coderInboxFetchRecordsService.saveCoderConfiguration(requestvalue);

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(" Exception while fetching record from DB", e.getMessage());
}

return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(status);
}


public class CoderConfigvalue implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1749526768701725321L;
private String facilitycode;
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonProperty("GenericValidation")
private List<Map<String, Boolean>> GenericValidation;
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonProperty("HL7Specification")
private List<Map<String, Boolean>> HL7Specification;
```

Comment: That's not a list, it's a single object

Comment: you can't make a list from a single object. Please ensure you actually understand the structure and syntax of the JSON you're working with. Also, you didn't show us your code which causes the error, so helping you correct it (other than advising you you're probably deserialising to the wrong structure) will not be possible.

Comment: @ ADyson i meant that hwo i can pass this to my controller and store in DB

Comment: well it seems like your controller is probably receiving it, but it cannot deserialise it into an object because you're telling it to deserialise it into a list structure, when the JSON is not a list (it's a single object). Although, it's hard to be sure because we haven't got any code, nor do we know how precisely you sent the request from PostMan. Are you saying you just want to store the raw JSON string directly into a field in the database, rather than deserialising its contents? Also, again, please _show your code_. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: @ ADyson i understood can you tell me how I can catch raw json in my controller so i can push to DB. meant that what will be in my @RequestBody parameter?

Comment: Maybe just accept a single string as the input parameter rather than any kind of object. For the last time, _show your code_ so we can advise you better.

Comment: @ ADyson added  sample code

Comment: I personally am not a Spring expert, but it seems similar to ASP.NET MVC. If you literally want to get the raw JSON string I would try maybe changing `insertCoderConfiguration(@RequestBody CoderConfigvalue requestvalue` to `insertCoderConfiguration(@RequestBody string requestvalue` . That way it should just read in the raw string without trying to convert it into an object. You might also have to change the content-type header in your PostMan request to be text rather than JSON, I'm not sure. I should think somewhere, Spring has docs on how its model binder works, so you can check.